# Get line of exception in my own exception class

Tags: exception, error-handling, python-3.2

Is there any way, how to find out line of code, where I called: raise MyError("something")??

I have code like this:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

Can I get the line of exception in this class?

Calling like this:

```
try:
    somethin()
except:
    raise MyError("abc")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [traceback](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#traceback) for this.

Comment: I tried traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout), but it prints nothing. That's strange, isn't it?